# How to interact with the Windows applications with GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I want to write a convenient front-end to the old and ugly Win95 application. I nailed the problem to this:

1. Invoke the target executable;
2. Wait for application window to appear;
3. Wait for message box (i hope it is a message box) to appear;
4. Trigger an onClick event for the "OK" button of the message box;
5. Wait for the application to exit.

1st and 5th items are easy, it is just the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` stuff; but i have no idea where to start with the rest of items. How could it be done?

Comment: What have you found? If clicking is the only thing that needs to be done, take a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: Might want to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx.

Comment: [SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/) might do what you want. It's not C#, but it could help.

Comment: Take a look at the windows automation framework, this is a good starter http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141842/Automate-your-UI-using-Microsoft-Automation-Framew

Comment: Is it not an option to patch the original executable to not trigger the MessageBox?

Comment: @MikeMiller Could you please write your comment as an answer so that i could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the windows automation framework, this is a good starter [codeproject.com/Articles/141842/](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141842/Automate-your-UI-using-Microsoft-Automation-Framew)

Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too much of an effort you could open up the executable in a disassembler (like ollydbg) and simply NOP the call to the messagebox. Then from C# you could simply wait for the process to exit instead of dismissing the messagebox using code.

Comment: Unfortunately, disassembler is out of question.